# Android - Restrict to launch

Tags: android, service, background

I found really interesting option in **Lenovo K5**

[image]

When this option is active, my background services doesn't activated after restart of the device. I searched everywhere in the web, and I set some tweaks in the manifest, but nothing helps.

I notice that in some apps, that option is not activated, like Facebook or Viber. So when they can made it, I'm sure that it have some workaround of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    // some logic
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // some logic
}
}
```

MyAutoStart.java

```
public class MyAutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {

/**
 * Listens for Android's BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and then executes
 * the onReceive() method.
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ServiceMaps.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyAutoStart"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MyService" />
```

Comment: Did you find solution of this? I've similar too... system apps runs without this option by efault, but each other have it checked, but its bad option :(